# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. IIS

Tags: http, iis, permissions, http-status-code-403, iis-manager

I have seen all the other Forbidden Access is denied post, But i have added a DefaultDocument and have enabled Directory Browsing.

When I enable Directory Browsing I see the files but once i click a folder or file it says 
Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.
The resource cannot be found.

But I check the physical location and everything is there nothing is corrupted.

Also when I add the default document it is a .cshtml but nothing happens, I see the same 403 Forbidden Error.

I would appreciate any words of advice or tips to help me resolve this issue.

I thank you guys in advance.

Comment: How is your website's authentication configured?

Comment: @Andrea I have enabled Anonymous Authentication and Forms Authentication